# Check Constraint in a tuple

Tags: postgresql, constraints, tuples

For all presidents born after 1800, the party can never be ’WHIG’.

```
alter table president
add constraint whig_check check (birth_year > 1800 and party <> 'WHIG');
```

It gives me that some row violates it but I checked and it doesn't.
 I think the system sees it as two seperate constraint but they should be together. How do I make it this work?

Comment: 29 but that's good. because it's correct that nobody after 1800 has 'WHIG' as their party. If I query the ones who do have 'WHIG' after 1800 it returns 0 as it should so no row violates the constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the logic backwards. use instead:

```
alter table president
add constraint whig_check check (birth_year <= 1800 OR party <> 'WHIG');
```

Comment: Because the logical implication `P -> Q` is the same as `-P | Q` and the OP is trying to express an implication, not a simple conjunction.

Comment: In plain English: *"Either the guy was born before 1800, or his party can't be ’WHIG’."*